# Better way of selecting the card being hovered with Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, arrays, nodelist

i have to codes. One works fine but i'm looking for a better way to iterate the script.

i need the code to change the current active class on the card the mouse is being hovered on and then replace the image box appropriately.

below is the code that works fine.

```js
function cardHover(t){

    const cardItemAll = document.querySelectorAll('.card__item');
    const cardImageAll = document.querySelectorAll('#cardImage');
    const cardFirstChild = document.querySelector('.card__item:nth-child(1)');
    const cardSecondChild = document.querySelector('.card__item:nth-child(2)');
    const cardThirdChild = document.querySelector('.card__item:nth-child(3)');
    const imageFirstChild = document.querySelector('#cardImage:nth-child(1)');
    const imageSecondChild = document.querySelector('#cardImage:nth-child(2)');
    const imageThirdChild = document.querySelector('#cardImage:nth-child(3)');

    cardItemAll.forEach(e => {

        if (e.classList.contains('active')) {

            e.classList.remove('active');            
        }
        
    });

    t.classList.add('active');

    if (t == cardFirstChild) {

        cardImageAll.forEach(e => {

            if (e.classList.contains('active')) {
    
                e.classList.remove('active');            
            }
            
        });

        imageFirstChild.classList.add('active');

        console.log(t);

    }

    if (t == cardSecondChild) {

        cardImageAll.forEach(e => {

            if (e.classList.contains('active')) {
    
                e.classList.remove('active');            
            }
            
        });

        imageSecondChild.classList.add('active');

        console.log(t);

    }

    if (t == cardThirdChild) {

        cardImageAll.forEach(e => {

            if (e.classList.contains('active')) {
    
                e.classList.remove('active');            
            }
            
        });

        imageThirdChild.classList.add('active');

        console.log(t);

    }

}
```

```css
.card {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 7fr 3fr;
      grid-template-columns: 7fr 3fr;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1.5rem;
          column-gap: 1.5rem;
}

.card__list {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-rows: (auto)[3];
      grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  row-gap: 1.5rem;
}

.card__item {
  background-color: #f5e7d9;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.card__item.active, .card__item:hover {
  background-color: #d0b28f;
}

.card__item.active h2, .card__item.active p, .card__item:hover h2, .card__item:hover p {
  color: #3e2e1b;
}

.card__item__title, .card__item__lead {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.card__image {
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #d0b28f;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.image-1 {
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/3032153/pexels-photo-3032153.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3 ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3 ease-in-out;
}

.image-1.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image-2 {
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/5776286/pexels-photo-5776286.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3 ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3 ease-in-out;
}

.image-2.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image-3 {
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/4985297/pexels-photo-4985297.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3 ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3 ease-in-out;
}

.image-3.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card container">

            <div class="card__list">
    
                <div class="card__item active" onmouseover="cardHover(this)">
                    <h2 class="card__title">Building Brand</h2>
                    <p class="card__lead">Anim aliqua nostrud cillum ea duis commodo sint consectetur et occaecat exercitation. Consectetur ut occaecat qui quis. Qui veniam fugiat est ullamco velit cupidatat est pariatur.</p>
                </div>
    
                <div class="card__item" onmouseover="cardHover(this)">
                    <h2 class="card__title">Building Brand</h2>
                    <p class="card__lead">Anim aliqua nostrud cillum ea duis commodo sint consectetur et occaecat exercitation. Consectetur ut occaecat qui quis. Qui veniam fugiat est ullamco velit cupidatat est pariatur.</p>
                </div>
    
                <div class="card__item" onmouseover="cardHover(this)">
                    <h2 class="card__title">Building Brand</h2>
                    <p class="card__lead">Anim aliqua nostrud cillum ea duis commodo sint consectetur et occaecat exercitation. Consectetur ut occaecat qui quis. Qui veniam fugiat est ullamco velit cupidatat est pariatur.</p>
                </div>
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="card__image">
    
                <div id="cardImage" class="image image-1 active"></div>
                <div id="cardImage" class="image image-2"></div>
                <div id="cardImage" class="image image-3"></div>
    
            </div>

        </div>
```

What i want to improve is the way the javascript finds the card being hovered and then displaying the correct picture.

Here is the Javascript for the one i'm trying to improve

```js
function cardHover(t){

    const cardItemAll = document.querySelectorAll('.card__item');
    const cardImageAll = document.querySelectorAll('#cardImage');
    const imageNthChild = document.querySelectorAll('#cardImage:nth-child(n)');
    const imageArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(imageNthChild);

    cardItemAll.forEach(e => {

        if (e.classList.contains('active')) {

            e.classList.remove('active');            
        }
        
    });

    t.classList.add('active');

    imageArray.forEach(function(i) {

        cardImageAll.forEach(e => {

            if (e.classList.contains('active')) {
    
                e.classList.remove('active');
    
                e.classList.remove('show');  

                e.classList.add('hide'); 

            } else {

                if (e.classList.contains('hide')) {

                    e.classList.remove('hide');

                }

            }
            
        });

        if(this.addEventListener("mouseover", function(c) {

            c.classList.remove('hide');
    
            c.classList.add('show');
    
            c.classList.add('active');

            console.log(c);
            
        })) {           
    
            console.log(i);

        }
        
    });

    for (i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {

        console.log(imageArray[i]);

        cardImageAll.forEach(e => {

            if (e.classList.contains('active')) {
    
                e.classList.remove('active');
    
                e.classList.remove('show');  

                e.classList.add('hide');            
            }
            
        });

        if (t == imageArray[i]) {
    
            imageArray[i].classList.remove('hide');
            
            imageArray[i].classList.add('show');
    
            imageArray[i].classList.add('active');
    
            console.log(imageArray[i]);
    
        }

    }
    
   }
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You don't need to iterate anything. Store a reference to the hovered card in a variable, and when a new card is hovered, use the variable to remove the active class from the previously hovered card.

Comment: You can simplify your code using `this` operators. "eventlisteners for classes, on hover, hide all, show this" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: @Teemu how would i do that?

Comment: @Coll I tried to use `this` operators as well but it didn't seem to work when i tried it.